# Ajax JSON data and lightbox conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a gallery setup with the lightbox plugin [lightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/)

The gallery works perfect with static HTML. The problem arises when I dynamically grab API data and try to have the lightbox working on those items.

I can't seem to get another lightbox to both work with this function **and** load an HTML block from the page correctly (load the one that's been dynamically generated). This app does the correct HTML grabs, if I can get the conflict resolved.

Any initial thoughts? Anyone else run into anything similar?

JS:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------// Calling Lightgallery //---------------//
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
    $('#photoBox').lightGallery({
        selector: '.tile',
        download: false,
        counter: false,
        zoom: false,
        thumbnail: false,
        mode: 'lg-fade'
    });

// ----------------------------------------------------------------//
// ---------------// Unsplash Photos //---------------//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------//

// Filter Difference based on button click
$('button').click(function () {
    $('button').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var unsplashAPI = "#URL";
    var order = $(this).text();
    var sortOptions = {
        order_by: order,
        format: "json"
    };
    function displayPhotos(data) {
    var photoData = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, photo) {
            photoData += '<a class="tile" data-src="' + photo.urls.regular + '">' + '<img alt class="photo" src="' + photo.urls.regular + '">' + '<div class="caption-box" id="' +  photo.id + '">' + '<h1 class="photo-title">' + 'Photo By: ' + photo.user.name + '</h1>' + '<p class="photo-description"> Description: Awesome photo by ' + photo.user.name + ' aka: ' + photo.user.username + ' So far this photo has ' + '<span>' + photo.likes + '</span>' + ' Likes' + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</a>';
        });
        $('#photoBox').html(photoData);
    }
$.getJSON(unsplashAPI, sortOptions, displayPhotos);
}); // End button
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="content" id="photoBox"></div>
```

-- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the plugin after the data is appended to the page

```
 function displayPhotos(data) {
    var photoData = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, photo) {
            photoData += '<a class="tile" data-src="' + photo.urls.regular + '">' + '<img alt class="photo" src="' + photo.urls.regular + '">' + '<div class="caption-box" id="' +  photo.id + '">' + '<h1 class="photo-title">' + 'Photo By: ' + photo.user.name + '</h1>' + '<p class="photo-description"> Description: Awesome photo by ' + photo.user.name + ' aka: ' + photo.user.username + ' So far this photo has ' + '<span>' + photo.likes + '</span>' + ' Likes' + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</a>';
        });
        $('#photoBox').html(photoData);
         $('#photoBox').lightGallery({
        selector: '.tile',
        download: false,
        counter: false,
        zoom: false,
        thumbnail: false,
        mode: 'lg-fade'
    });
    }
```